# How to Update Top 1 record from Azure Synapses Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

I am getting data from multiple sources into Data Warehouse while joining multiple source systems am getting redundant data due to some of the column changes. I want to update first record quantity of each group to "0".

I tried by creating cte with update statement it's not working. am getting below error
"The query processor could not produce a query plan because the DML statement is not yet supported."

I do understand Azure Data-warehouse won't support cte with update statement but i want to know will there any way that i can achieve this?

Can anyone help me out on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO .

CTE is not yet supported in SQLDW , hence the error . We have a work around called out here . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/53294/recursive-cte-work-around.html

Please let me know how it goes . If you can share some data and it will more helpful .